# If i enter a long text in my elastic ion-textarea.then while scrolling down it is automatically scrolling up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
 <ion-textarea fz-elastic

       [(ngModel)]="addMe">

     </ion-textarea>
```

if i am pasting a long text, let's say 1000 words and then after pasting such text i am scrolling to the bottom of the page just to see the last point of my pasted text , then page automatically scrolls up. Seems like it is not allowing me to scroll to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the HTML code i used:

```
<textarea #myInput id="myInput" rows="1" placeholder="Share" [(ngModel)]="addMe" (keyup)="resize()"></textarea>
```

Following is the JS code, Don't forget to import ViewChild and ElementRef

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core'; //  imports ViewChild, ElementRef

@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;

resize() { //Resize function is increasing the Size of text area, as our text is increasing

    if(this.addMe === '' || this.addMe === null) {
      this.myInput.nativeElement.style.height = 'auto'; // returns the teatarea height to normal when the input is empty
    } else {
      this.myInput.nativeElement.style.height = this.myInput.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `ion-textarea` inside a `ion-item`? This could do the trick since using the textarea without it breaks the component in many ways.